# Create pdf document in SwiftUI - (IOS and MacOS)

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swiftui, swift5

I am trying to build a billing(**Invoice**) application in **SwiftUI**. that works on ipad and mac. i need some help in creating pdf documents, how to convert my data to a pdf document?

Answer (score 2):

**iOS** has `PDFKit` framework specifically used for creating and manipulating **PDF** type documents.

---

Read more about `PDFKit` and how to use it in the following sources:

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit)

[Blog post](https://www.raywenderlich.com/4023941-creating-a-pdf-in-swift-with-pdfkit)